# Python. Проблема в скрипте

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование, idle

Здравствуйте!

```
def Cesar(s,alp,rot):
    str=[]
    i=0
    while (i<=len(s)):
        str.append(alp[alp.find(s[i])+rot])
    return str

s=input()
rot=int(input())
alp='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
print(Cesar(s,alp,rot)
```

При запуске не работает. Ввожу строку, ввожу число. Далее не происходит ничего и программа всё ещё требует ввод данных. 
Программа должна выдать строку смещенную на rot знаков. Вопрос: В чём ошибка?

Заранее спасибо. Очень прошу помочь

Comment: Почему ваш цикл внутри функции должен вообще завершиться? Программа не ввода ждёт, а бесконечный цикл выполняет.

Comment: @retorta вполне конечный. Завершится, исчерпав всю память.

Answer (score 2):

```
def Cesar(s,alp,rot):
    str=[]
    i=0
    while (i<len(s)):
        str.append(alp[((alp.find(s[i]) + rot) % len(alp)])
        i += 1
    return str
```

Но это не-pythonic, лучше

```
def Cesar(s,alp,rot):
    str=[]
    for l in s:
         str.append(alp[((alp.find(l) + rot) % len(alp)])
    return ''.join(str)
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо. Но тогда 2 вопроса: что значит знак вопроса в данном случае и почему нельзя просто вернуть str?

Comment: @FlashSpoker Знака вопроса я не вижу. Если Вы о `%` - это деление по модулю, иначе Вы будете вылетать за пределы массива. Вернуть `str` конечно можно, но ИМО логично возвращать именно строку а не список символов.